# How do I migrate only the items that previously failed?

Tags: 7, migrations

I have a migration class that has imported 2000 items correctly, but failed to import 40 of them.

Now I have corrected the import class, but I don't want to do a rollback and a full reimport/migrate.

Is there a possibility to import/migrate only the 40 failed items?

Comment: Have you tried executing again the migrate after correcting the errors ? It _should_ work.

Comment: As @drcelus says - migrate should update already migrated items, not duplicate it. but the only way in your case is to test it, and if it'll duplicate, you will have to rollback anyway.

Comment: @drcelus: yes i have tried it, but without "--update" migrate module do not import nothing new. I have resolved with the "--update" option. However: thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the "--needs-update" option as "migrate-import Article --needs-update" .

You might need to status of needs-update field for these 40 records as needs_update=1.

This option is only needed when your Drupal DB is on a different DB server from your source data. Otherwise, these records get migrated with just migrate-import.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Via "drush" call the migration with "--update" and the process create the remaining items.

```
$  drush mi --update MigrateMhtLinks
Processed 2040 (40 created, 2000 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) in 9.5 sec (1734/min) - done with 'MigrateMhtLinks'
```

Comment: --update will migrate ALL items not just the previous that failed

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution I found consists in 2 queries in the source and the destination dbs:

1) In the migration class, a 1st query in the destination db selects source ids => 

`$ids = array(); 
$query = db_select('migrate_message_[migration_class_name]', 'm'); 
$query->fields('m', array('sourceid1')); 
$result = $query->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) { 
  $ids[] = $record['sourceid1']; 
}`

2) Then add a condition in 2nd query, the migration source query: 
`$query->condition([map_id], $ids, 'IN');`

Comment: how to do this?

Comment: I suggest you integrate (move) your prior comment into your actual answer!

Comment: Your suggestion is meaningful :-) Done !

Comment: Happy to see you took my advice ... Or should I rather say that IMO you succeeded in my challenge in my the very first comment? What you may not know/realize yet, is that I posted that 1st comment instead of hitting the "vote to delete"-button when your first version of your answer showed up in the low quality posts review queue (that would have taken "me" less effort, while no every new user likes such kinds of comments). Anyway, here goes your first +1, way to go!

Answer (score 0):

The reason when "drush mi some_d6_migration_name" runs again, and it migrates nothing new is drush considers this migration has been finished/completed already. There should be 2040 records in table "migrate_map_some_d6_migration_name", including those 40 failed items.

If a message such as '2000 items has been migrated, 40 items are not processed' is returned when drush mi runs for the first time, and then when "drush mi some_d6_migration_name" runs again, it should process those 40 'unprocessed' items.

So for those failed items, I think you can delete failed records from this table "migrate_map_some_d6_migration_name", with something as

```
DELETE FROM migrate_map_some_d6_migration_name where source_ids_hash in (select source_ids_hash from migrate_message_some_d6_migration_name)
```

or this one if this migration has only one destid.

```
DELETE FROM migrate_map_some_d6_migration_name WHERE destid1 IS NULL
```

Above commands will make those failed items become 'unprocessed' items. Then run "drush cr" to clear cache(this step may be needed or not) and run "drush mi some_d6_migration_name" again. This time it should only migrate previously failed items.